# Gathering of water before modern cleansing methods

Tags: middle-ages, inventions

Sorry if this is a stupid question but i simply could not get my head around it.

Before modern day cleansing of salt water to produce drinkable water how was this gathered? especially in areas that does not have fresh water lakes?

Comment: I'm not sue that desalinization was ever a significant water source - people settle near sources of fresh water.

Comment: I don't have the time to fully answer it now but I disagree with the close votes, as their is a [legitimate answer](http://www.freedrinkingwater.com/resource-history-of-clean-drinking-water.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In areas without rivers or lakes, people [collected rainwater](http://www.rainwaterharvesting.org/Rural/Traditional1.htm) and dug [wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_well).

Comment: Might be useful to quote a definition of the word *cistern* here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cistern